# How to give WSO2 time interval for consuming messages

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic

I need to configure wso2 to consume message one by one with time interval from activemq. Is there a way to consume just a message on given time?

When there are many message on activemq, WSO2 consumes all messages and call backend service. Backend service does not handle all incoming message.

I created one jms inbound endpoint and one proxy service, but I didn't find a property or a way to do.

Inbound Endpoint:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
                 name="activemqDeneme"
                 sequence="esb-QueueSQ"
                 onError="conf:/sequences/esb.faultSQ.xml"
                 protocol="jms"
                 suspend="false">
   <parameters>
      <parameter name="interval">60000</parameter>
      <parameter name="sequential">false</parameter>
      <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
      <parameter name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</parameter>
      <parameter name="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://localhost:6052</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">QueueConnectionFactory</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryType">queue</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">queue_request</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionTransacted">false</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.jms.SessionAcknowledgement">AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.jms.CacheLevel">3</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.jms.SubscriptionDurable">false</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">application/json</parameter>
      <parameter name="transport.jms.SharedSubscription">false</parameter>
   </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

Proxy Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Queue"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="jms">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <sequence description="call activemq" key="esb-QueueSQ"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">queue_request</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules xmlns="">
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
         <default>application/json</default>
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try with

```
  <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
```

when set to false it will probably consume them all in parallel. After your sequence needs to be sequential as well.

Comment: I tried, but it still consumes many message like 6 messages in a second. Maybe it consumes sequentially, but what I need that it should consume one message in a second.

Comment: Then I guess you sequence "esb-QueueSQ" is not sequential (does it perform a call for instance, in this case you can try to add a parameter blocking="true") ?

Comment: thank you nicolas. There was a call without bloking="true".